# Renting bikes each place visited in Denmark or in 1 place and carry them, and how will they be equipped?

Tags: bicycles, denmark, copenhagen

We are staying 7-10 days in and around Copenhagen in August. We plan to tour the city by bike (by ourselves) and take trains out for day/multiday bicycle trips in several places.

My question is whether we should try to rent the bikes in Copenhagen and carry them with us in the train, or rent at the station where we arrive. This is both in terms of price (will we get a much better fare for a 9-day rental rather than three 3-day rentals?) and also in terms of the equipment of the bikes: maybe it's better to have city bikes in Copenhagen and mountain bikes in, e.g., Møn?

Also, for our 3-day tour to Møn at least, we need rear racks that'll accept (Vaude™) panniers, I think they're pretty universal but the rentals I get in France are usually not compatible. Any info whether you can get that appreciated.

Some more details if you want to know/have further thoughts on feasibility:

*For Møn, we plan a 2 or 3 days bike tour: leave our luggage in Copenhagen with LuggaeHero, take a train to Vordingborg, stay first night in Stege after going to the beach North of it, then following day to Møns Klint and back to Stege, or elsewhere, and then a smaller tour in Falster maybe before we get back to catch a train.
We're not sure whether we rent the bikes/keep bikes rented for a longer period from Copenhagen or whether we rent bikes in Vordingborg.*

*Then for Aerø we can't leave luggage in Copenhagen or carry bikes from there as we are not going back to Copenhagen after that. We plan to get train to Odense, leave luggage in left-luggage service at station, rent bikes and cycle or take train to Svendborg and ferry to island. Back next day, via Egeskov probably? Again, not sure whether we cycle Fyn or not, and if not, whether it's best to rent bikes somewhere in Fyn or direct in Aerø (which means we need to use same port there when arriving and leaving).
(not e-bikes preferably)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of questions, which essentially depend on your own preferences and details in your planning, which you don't share with us.

What kind of bicycle you prefer to ride, a city bike, a touring bike or a mountain bike is something you have to decide upon. What makes you think that a mountain bike will be more suitable for a ride around Møn than any other bike? If you are staying on roads (be it regular roads or gravel roads) and you are not planning to go off road, there is usually no need for a mountain bike, but that is valid everywhere and not a particular advice for Møn. Mountain bike wheels are built to give you grip on rough underground and are (much) harder to pedal on roads than bikes with wheels made for using on-road. Remember also, that mountain bikes usually don't have luggage racks.

There are many bicycle rentals in Copenhagen and easy to find rentals everywhere else in Denmark. Almost without exception, it is quite a bit cheaper to rent for a longer period than for many shorter periods. Just to compare prices at an arbitrary rental in Copenhagen, they charge DKK 125 for one day, DKK 225 for three days and DKK 495 for nine days for the cheapest category of bikes. But, you must also remember that it is usually not free to take bikes on the train in Denmark. For example from Copenhagen to Vordinborg, you pay DKK 36 for a bike ticket if I understand the price correctly. If you plan to travel a lot around, it may still be cheaper to rent at different locations for shorter periods. Also remember, that you must usually return the bikes where you picked them up. I've seen chains of rental stores in other countries offering to pickup and return at different locations, but I don't think that is common in Denmark.

Vaude panniers are indeed not compatible with all luggage racks, but if you go to a larger rental and tell them when booking that you need such a rack, there should be no problem for the bike rental to arrange that for you. Many bike rentals also offer panniers for rent if that is easier for you than to bring your own.

Comment: Regarding:
"But, you must also remember that it is usually not free to take bikes on the train in Denmark."
Correct, but a few extra details: All long distance trains requires a ticket, and in the summer a paid reservation icket is required in these trains as well. The local commuter trains (S-tog) around Copenhagen doesn't require either tickets or reservations.
See https://www.dsb.dk/en/travelers/bicycles/